# How do I determine total network bandwidth usage on windows server 2016?

Tags: networking, monitoring, windows-server-2016

I am currently looking at 1Gb/s download and 35 MB/s upload over coax. We are looking at setting up some VOIP services etc which will be impacted by such a low upload speed. How do I determine what the max bandwidth usage for the day was? I'm aware that netstat, netsh, and network monitor provide information regarding individual processes but I cannot find the data I need to determine whether upgrading to fiber would be marginally beneficial or entirely necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Netstat, netsh, performance monitor, network monitor

I can obtain the information regarding any connection in particular but i need something more akin to over all statistics so that i can make an informed decision regarding our network limitations ( fiber vs coax)....Do we need an additional 200 mb/s ? etc

Comment: Feels more like this should have been asked on superuser

Answer (score 0):

Typical VOIP services only require a few kilobytes per second of upload bandwidth per phone call.  Do you anticipate having many (hundreds of) concurrent phone calls which would add up to 35MBytes/s (or more likely 35Mbits/sec).  As an aside, network bandwidth is typically expressed with big-M and little-b (e.g. Mb) to denote megabits per second.

I would suggest first using a utility like [SolarWinds RealTime Bandwidth Monitor](https://www.solarwinds.com/free-tools/real-time-bandwidth-monitor/) to look at your router/gateways utilization.